# R: Barchart with specific values

Tags: r, bar-chart

```
Name    Amount
AAAA    5.6
BBBB    1.2
CCCC    7.8
DDDD    3.4
```

I have the above very simple set of data.  How can I make a barchart in R where the bars are the heights of the values in Amount?  For example, I would have bar AAAA with a Y value of 5.6, bar BBBB with a Y value of 1.2, etc.  I have used barplot before, but only in conjunction with the table function, which doesn't help me in this case.

Thanks!

Comment: you mean `barplot(df$Amount, names.arg = df$Name)` ?

Comment: This is succinctly answered in the help file: `?barplot()`

Comment: We can try `barplot(setNames(df$Amount, df$Name))`

Comment: That'll do...should have realized how easy it was.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

There is an argument `names.arg` in `barplot` which is used to set the names,

```
 barplot(df$Amount, names.arg = df$Name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ggplot2, it could be done with geom_bar():

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(Name=c("AAAA", "BBBB", "CCCC", "DDDD"), Amount=c(5.6,1.2,7.8,3.4))
ggplot(df, aes(x=Name, y=Amount)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Without using additional libraries it could be done with the barplot() function and passing the column 'Name' as the names.arg argument (as pointed out by Sotos):

```
barplot(df$Amount, names.arg = df$Name)
```

Comment: your `barplot` option is already answered, no point in including it in your answer